# Macbook Pro Touch Bar 15 inch 2018 ssd Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

Can i upgrade macbook pro (2018) ssd drive with a new one? When i google it, i found Samsung 970 Evo m.2 "NVMe" 1 tb may be supported. NVMe interface is required by macbook pro but is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for ordinary users to replace the SSD in the 2018 MacBook Pro. You'll need specialized equipment and training in order to be able to replace the flash storage that is soldered directly on to the main board.

You can upgrade your storage by adding extra storage, such as for example a USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 connected external drive.

Comment: So it is technically possible for the technical services right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "technical services". Is it "technically possible" to replace the SSD - yes. Is it "realistically possible" for any non-specialized technician - no. If you want an ordinary "repair center" to replace the SSD, they'll probably do it by replacing the whole logic board.

Comment: You might want to add that this kind of procedure is forbidden to do for AASP, not offered by Apple in any way, and hence destroys any warranty AppleCare. (+: has really anyone ever done this on soldered SSDs in MBPs?)

Comment: being that different SSD chips would have a different pinout and internal layout (remember the hard drive controller is soldered on the motherboard too) this would be extremely hard to do.  I think it falls under the category that its theoretical the Sun may not rise tomorrow but highly unlikely.  The only way I can see doing it is replacing the motherboard but again as LangLangC pointed out this changes the electronic serial number (unless you have access to the parts and tools to set the serial number on a new board) and changes the specs, this voids any warranty.